# Command not found error in Matlab, when tried to run system commands

Tags: macos, bash, matlab, path, osx-mavericks

I am trying to run image processing software called Flirt in Matlab. When I try

```
system'flirt'
```

I get a `/bin/bash: flirt: command not found` error.

If I try `system('/usr/local/fsl/bin/flirt');` then it works fine. Typing just `flirt` in terminal also launches the program.

Is there a way of setting Matlab to find this program in path and running it without giving its full address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check system path from within MATLAB using:

`getenv('PATH')`

Set from within MATLAB using:

`setenv('PATH', [getenv('PATH') ':/usr/local/fsl/bin']);`

If that fixes it, you can add the `setenv` line to your MATLAB startup file.

Comment: Just to extend this answer a little: the startup file is a file called `startup.m` that you place anywhere in the Matlab search path. You can see the Matlab search path by executing `path` at the Matlab command prompt.